# Passing multiple source to single file in @drawable

Tags: android

Currently I have a single button with image bound to it and I wanted to add a click effect on that(not click event, a effect). Well it worked fine. I created two xml in my drawable folder and added styles and gradient to it. But now I want to add few more buttons and apply the same click effect on them. One way I can create multiple xml files for as many buttons created. But what happened to code reuse? I want to reuse the same xml files for styling other buttons too. Can it be done? thanks in advance.

My button.xml file is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/stb" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gradient" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gradient" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/stb" />
</selector>
```

And my gradient.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/stb"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <gradient android:angle="90" android:startColor="#990f0f10" 
                       android:centerColor="#990d0d0f" 
                       android:endColor="#995d5d5e"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I could really use some help here. Please help me out or is there any other approach to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the very same xml selector drawable to as many views as you want. Just set the other button's background via XML:

```
android:background="@drawable/button"
```

or code:

```
yourSecondButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
```

Comment: But my button.xml is taking the image source from @drawable, so how can I dynamically allocate other images too?

Comment: Why do you need them dynamically? You did not mention that in your question.